# Erro ORA-28000: the account is locked aparecendo com frequência

Tags: oracle

Trabalho em uma instituição onde utilizamos uma aplicação que conecta em uma base de dados ORACLE.

Recentemente a senha do usuário do BD foi alterada, e a mensagem the account is locked aparece com frequência...

Creio que algum computador de algum usuário esteja com a senha desatualizada, ai quando ele abre a aplicação ela tenta conectar utilizando a senha errada e trava o usuário do BD... É possível identificar o IP ou nome do computador quem está tentando fazer esses acessos?

Comment: faz uma consulta na `v$sessions` e vê quem ta fazendo isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, 
Voce pode tentar identificar este host na log do listener do seu servidor de banco de dados. Outra alternativa para evitar que o usuário seja bloqueado até se voce possa identificar a origem das tentativas de conexão com a senha antiga, é alterar o profile deste usuário para não bloquear após as tentativas com a senha incorreta.

Abs,
Renato